# How to ignore `mexopts.sh` when compiling MEX files for Matlab?

Tags: matlab, mex

The `-f` command-line argument to `mex` allows to specify the location of the `mexopts.sh` that we wish to use. But is there a way to tell Matlab to ignore `mexopts.sh`? In order to compile a specific MEX file I need to specify `CC`, `CFLAGS`, etc., directly on the command line when invoking `mex`. Values already given in `mexopts.sh` cause a conflict and cause `mex` to fail.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not specify an empty mexopts.sh file?

Comment: Because this is part of software that will be distributed. Are you suggesting we ship an empty `mexopts.sh`? I guess that's a possibility.

Comment: You could just ship a makefile that invokes the compiler directly and creates a shared library with the appropriate `mexext`. After all, there's nothing special about a mex file other than the predefined `mexFunction` entry point. This is what I'd prefer unless I was targeting multiple compilers / OSes, in which case it's nice to have the `mex` function manage the details.

Comment: That's precisely what we're doing but it seems that `mex` is grabbing options from the default `mexopts.sh` that are not specified on the command line. I can tell because it tries to use different C flags.

Comment: @Dominique I meant ship a makefile that calls GCC (or whatever compiler you're using) directly. Don't call the `mex` function, that will read options for the currently configured compiler from *mexopts.sh*. You can create a mex file yourself by having GCC create a shared library (with the correct extension) and exporting `mexFunction`.

Comment: @Dominique You have any success with this? Would you be against just specifying the options you don't want with `COMPFLAGS = ''` or something along these lines? Also, did specifying an empty .sh file and using `-f` to point to it work as per Daniel's suggestion?